# Using serialized query in Wordpress with Ajax

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I have a serialized query in Wordpress that looks like this:

```
"a:66:{s:9:"post_type";s:11:"exhibitions";s:8:"meta_key";s:14:"event_date_end";s:7:"orderby";s:14:"meta_value_num";s:5:"order";s:4:"DESC";s:14:"posts_per_page";i:1;s:10:"meta_query";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:3:"key";s:14:"event_date_end";s:7:"compare";s:1:"<";s:5:"value";s:8:"20191008";}}s:5:"error";s:0:"";s:1:"m";s:0:"";s:1:"p";i:0;s:11:"post_parent";s:0:"";s:7:"subpost";s:0:"";s:10:"subpost_id";s:0:"";s:10:"attachment";s:0:"";s:13:"attachment_id";i:0;s:4:"name";s:0:"";s:6:"static";s:0:"";s:8:"pagename";s:0:"";s:7:"page_id";i:0;s:6:"second";s:0:"";s:6:"minute";s:0:"";s:4:"hour";s:0:"";s:3:"day";i:0;s:8:"monthnum";i:0;s:4:"year";i:0;s:1:"w";i:0;s:13:"category_name";s:0:"";s:3:"tag";s:0:"";s:3:"cat";s:0:"";s:6:"tag_id";s:0:"";s:6:"author";s:0:"";s:11:"author_name";s:0:"";s:4:"feed";s:0:"";s:2:"tb";s:0:"";s:5:"paged";i:0;s:10:"meta_value";s:0:"";s:7:"preview";s:0:"";s:1:"s";s:0:"";s:8:"sentence";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:6:"fields";s:0:"";s:10:"menu_order";s:0:"";s:5:"embed";s:0:"";s:12:"category__in";a:0:{}s:16:"category__not_in";a:0:{}s:13:"category__and";a:0:{}s:8:"post__in";a:0:{}s:12:"post__not_in";a:0:{}s:13:"post_name__in";a:0:{}s:7:"tag__in";a:0:{}s:11:"tag__not_in";a:0:{}s:8:"tag__and";a:0:{}s:12:"tag_slug__in";a:0:{}s:13:"tag_slug__and";a:0:{}s:15:"post_parent__in";a:0:{}s:19:"post_parent__not_in";a:0:{}s:10:"author__in";a:0:{}s:14:"author__not_in";a:0:{}s:19:"ignore_sticky_posts";b:0;s:16:"suppress_filters";b:0;s:13:"cache_results";b:1;s:22:"update_post_term_cache";b:1;s:19:"lazy_load_term_meta";b:1;s:22:"update_post_meta_cache";b:1;s:8:"nopaging";b:0;s:17:"comments_per_page";s:2:"50";s:13:"no_found_rows";b:0;}"
```

The query has been serialized and assigned to a JS variable in a script tag, with the following:

```
var postsExhibitions = '<?php echo serialize( $query->query_vars ) ?>';
```

The string is then passed through AJAX to an action in the functions.php and I'm now trying to use `json_decode()` on the string, but nothing gets returned. I try to do the following:

```
$data = $_POST['query']; <----------- This is the serialized string
$data = stripslashes($data);
$return = json_decode($data, true);
```

If I echo the `$data` variable, it's showing the string like above in this post. But as soon as I try to output the `$return` variable, i.e. after the string has been decoded, it returns nothing.

Are there any steps that I'm missing here in "deserializing" the string?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `json_decode`, you are looking for the `unserialize` function.

SECURITY NOTE: If this page is public (outside of the WP Admin area), then adding the serialized query to the JS poses a security issue. If the page containing the `postsExhibitions` variable is exposed to the public any user will be able to change the query, and be able to query the WP application within the limits of the WP Query framework.

It is worth keeping the actual query within your back end code, and instead the javascript ajax call should only send some of the query parameter values. In this scenario it seems that only `event_date_end` is needed.

In any case, below is a working example that answers your question.

```
$query_unserialized_str = 'a:66:{s:9:"post_type";s:11:"exhibitions";s:8:"meta_key";s:14:"event_date_end";s:7:"orderby";s:14:"meta_value_num";s:5:"order";s:4:"DESC";s:14:"posts_per_page";i:1;s:10:"meta_query";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:3:"key";s:14:"event_date_end";s:7:"compare";s:1:"<";s:5:"value";s:8:"20191008";}}s:5:"error";s:0:"";s:1:"m";s:0:"";s:1:"p";i:0;s:11:"post_parent";s:0:"";s:7:"subpost";s:0:"";s:10:"subpost_id";s:0:"";s:10:"attachment";s:0:"";s:13:"attachment_id";i:0;s:4:"name";s:0:"";s:6:"static";s:0:"";s:8:"pagename";s:0:"";s:7:"page_id";i:0;s:6:"second";s:0:"";s:6:"minute";s:0:"";s:4:"hour";s:0:"";s:3:"day";i:0;s:8:"monthnum";i:0;s:4:"year";i:0;s:1:"w";i:0;s:13:"category_name";s:0:"";s:3:"tag";s:0:"";s:3:"cat";s:0:"";s:6:"tag_id";s:0:"";s:6:"author";s:0:"";s:11:"author_name";s:0:"";s:4:"feed";s:0:"";s:2:"tb";s:0:"";s:5:"paged";i:0;s:10:"meta_value";s:0:"";s:7:"preview";s:0:"";s:1:"s";s:0:"";s:8:"sentence";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:6:"fields";s:0:"";s:10:"menu_order";s:0:"";s:5:"embed";s:0:"";s:12:"category__in";a:0:{}s:16:"category__not_in";a:0:{}s:13:"category__and";a:0:{}s:8:"post__in";a:0:{}s:12:"post__not_in";a:0:{}s:13:"post_name__in";a:0:{}s:7:"tag__in";a:0:{}s:11:"tag__not_in";a:0:{}s:8:"tag__and";a:0:{}s:12:"tag_slug__in";a:0:{}s:13:"tag_slug__and";a:0:{}s:15:"post_parent__in";a:0:{}s:19:"post_parent__not_in";a:0:{}s:10:"author__in";a:0:{}s:14:"author__not_in";a:0:{}s:19:"ignore_sticky_posts";b:0;s:16:"suppress_filters";b:0;s:13:"cache_results";b:1;s:22:"update_post_term_cache";b:1;s:19:"lazy_load_term_meta";b:1;s:22:"update_post_meta_cache";b:1;s:8:"nopaging";b:0;s:17:"comments_per_page";s:2:"50";s:13:"no_found_rows";b:0;}';

$query_serialized_obj = unserialize( $query_unserialized_str );

print_r( $query_serialized_obj );
```